# Unable to get full definition of table in teradata

Tags: teradata

I am trying to get the definition of table in teradata and I am using following command

```
   show table DatabaseName.TableName;
```

This works fine for small tables but for large table it's not showing the full definition.
   Is there any other way for this.

I am running this query on teradata sql assistant version 13.0

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your're running a quite old version of SQL Assistant and probably a quite old version of ODBC, too.

There was a bug truncating the result of a SHOW TABLE, but it was fixed years ago.

Try to get a newer release of ODBC and/or SQL Assistant (or switch to the .NET provider)

http://downloads.teradata.com/download

Comment: Is there any other way that i get the full definition in this version only

Comment: IIRC this was an ODBC problem, so TD Administrator should truncate, too. Using anything else will work, e.g. BTEQ or any JDBC-based client.

Comment: I tried to execute the query through using bteq scripts (in unix) and I got the required output.